# Error adding base element using JavaScript in my HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, url

In my application I'm adding `base` HTML tag in the `head` section of my HTML file.

When I do so, I get the below error:

> core.js:1448 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): SecurityError: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'urlNumber1/#/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'urlNumber2' and URL 'urlNumber2/'.
>
> Error: Failed to execute 'replaceState' on 'History': A history state object with URL 'urlNumber1/#/' cannot be created in a document with origin 'urlNumber2' and URL 'urlNumber2/'.

I need tho add the urlNumber1 in the `base` element so the resources of my application, such as images, can be rendered in the application and this one can work as plan. Don't know where to start with this error.

I'm using Angular 5.

Comment: Which code did you add exactly?

Comment: I added html code: <base href="urlNumber1/" />

Comment: Are you using angular cli?

Comment: Yes @David, Using Angular CLI version 1.7.3

Comment: Try just setting the `--deploy-url` flag instead of base-href if your problem is with assets

Comment: I'm using angular cli but I'm not deploying with it or using any type of flags, the application doesn't work that way, the app is rendering an html page and using javascript I'm adding base element. Seems to be that the error appears way after the base addition, something is broke and I can't find what or why